# Mapview reset button and centering map to initial location

Tags: r, r-leaflet, tigris

I'm new to R and trying to work with mapview. I cant find a way to add a reset button or center and scale the map to a location.

For instance, right now I'm tring to use the Tigris package and merge it with a census data file I downloaded.I want to plot different columns of this data as a heatmap acccording to user selections. Initially, I want to show map centered and scaled to Lincoln park.

Ive been searching all day and have not been able to find a way to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think **mapview** will be the right tool for what you want to do. It doesn't suppoert heatmaps out-of-the box. More importantly, the zoom buttons are derived from the data. You need to use the respective **leaflet** and/or **leafem** functionality to achieve what you want.